# No Results returned for ROW_NUMBER() query

Tags: sql-order-by, where-clause, resultset, having-clause, row-number

I am getting "no results returned" for the following query:

```
SELECT 
    Referer 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CT.Referer ASC) AS RowNum, 
        CT.Referer, CT.LastModified
     FROM 
        ClickTrack CT 
     JOIN 
        OrderTrack OT ON OT.ClickTrackID = CT.ClickTrackID              
     GROUP BY 
        CT.Referer, CT.LastModified
     HAVING 
        LEN(CT.Referer) > 0) as num 
WHERE 
    RowNum = 1 
    AND LastModified BETWEEN '07/06/2013' and '08/05/2013'
```

Curiously, when I leave off `RowNum = 1`, I get the full list of values. I need to get one at a time though to assign to a variable and drop into a temporary table.

The end query will be in a while loop using scalar variables in place of the date ranges and `RowNum` comparison.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: can you provide some example data?  I used data I thought might make sense given the schema, but I'm always getting the results I expect.

Comment: also, what do you see when you change your select clause to be "SELECT RowNum, Referer"?  Does RowNum have a value?

Comment: ***What database*** (and which version) is this for? MySQL? Postgres? DB2? Oracle? SQL Server? Something else?

Comment: I'm working with MS Server 2008. Some sample data would be: Columns: [clicktrackid referer lastmodified] Data: [1 www.google.com 7/10/2013 19:31] [2 www.yahoo.com 7/11/2007 10:20] [3 www.google.co.uk 7/13/2013 15:33] [4 www.aol.com 8/16/2013 12:54]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking RowNum 1 may not have a date between your selections. Maybe put the date selection inside so that you know that the first one matches.

```
    SELECT Referer 
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CT.Referer ASC) 
    AS RowNum, CT.Referer, CT.LastModified
    FROM ClickTrack CT 
    JOIN OrderTrack OT ON OT.ClickTrackID = CT.ClickTrackID    
    WHERE CT.LastModified BETWEEN '07/06/2013' and '08/05/2013'          
    GROUP BY CT.Referer, CT.LastModified
    HAVING LEN(CT.Referer) > 0) as num 
    WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I believe you are correct. I tip my hat to you!